# Need help creating posts with wp_instert_post from JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am trying to insert JSON to wordpress using wp_insert_post. I have hit a brick wall. My code and some of my json can be seen below.

PHP:

```
<?php
$json_feed = "http://localhost/sample/ss-posts.json";
$json = file_get_contents($json_feed);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($obj as $article_array){
    $url = $article_array['url'];
    $title = $article_array['title'];
    $category = $article_array['category'];
    $large_summary = $article_array['wp_post_content'];

    $post = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $large_summary,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'post_template' => 'content.php'
        );

    wp_insert_post ($post, $wp_error);
}
?>
```

JSON data:

```
{
    "post":[
        {
            "title":"Choir to College to Commercial",
            "wp_post_title":"Choir to College to Commercial",
            "wp_post_content":"My entry into the world of music..."
        },
        {
            "title":"How to Master Vocal Technique",
            "wp_post_title":"How to Master Vocal Technique",
            "wp_post_content":"Acquiring command over vocal technique is like ..."
        },
        {
            "title":"How Do You Evaluate Singers?",
            "wp_post_title":"How Do You Evaluate Singers?",
            "wp_post_content":"Many lovers of singing say that they can't put to words ..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Error: When running this code I receive the following "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` in /Users/andrew/Desktop/newtest.php on line 6".

No Error when adding `foreach((array)$obj as $article_array){...}`

Also no error when wrapping entire foreach loop in an `if (is_object($obj)){...}` statement.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the `file_get_contents()` actually return valid json?

Comment: You are missing one level of 'post' in obj as seen in the json. So it should work if you just do 
$obj = json_decode($json, true)['post'];

Comment: After adding [post] to $obj && foreach we are now back to the original warning response: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/andrew/Desktop/newtest.php on line 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the structure of the JSON object is `{ "post":[ {}, {}, ... ] }`, by using json_decode the rusult will be `$obj['post'][ Array, Array, ... ]`. Thus in the `foreach` loop, you have to iterate through the `$obj['post']` array instead of the `$obj`

so the foreach has to be:

```
...
foreach($obj['post'] as $article_array){
...
```

Comment: After adding [post] to $obj && foreach we are now back to the original warning response: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/andrew/Desktop/newtest.php on line 6

Comment: wait, you mean you added the `['post']` in both places? Once at the foreach and once at the json_decode as mentoned in a comment above? You should add it only at one of the places

Comment: Yes use either one of the approaches, not both at once :)

Comment: @nikos.svnk Please explain why this solves the problem.

Comment: @Jack A. - there you are :)